# replay failure messages whenever I want in any time

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp, camel-sql

#camel Hi Devs, I am currently working on a camel to transform messages from Source to Target systems, I am stuck with an issue i.e., I want redelivery my message when any exceptions occurred or due to failure caused by endpoints. I had checked the camel docs then I got a info related to Redelivery Polices It is working as per the given delay time. But my problem is used to replay messages whenever I want. For example last year there are some messages which got failure those payloads are stored in my system. So I want to replay those messages this year. like Replay. Can any devs help me on this cause? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `DeadLetterChannel` EIP (https://camel.apache.org/components/3.16.x/eips/dead-letter-channel.html).

This will put your failed messages in a special channel (typically a **persistant** JMS queue). To replay a message, you only have to move it from the DLC ("myqueue.dead") to the original queue ("myqueue") .

Comment: Thanks for the response @TecheDeChoco. JMS messages can be moved to the DLQ queue. But how can replay file-based transactions?

Comment: In Camel, the unit of work is a **message** (more exactly an **Exchange**). Consumed files are turned by Camel into messages (of special body type) that can be put in DLQ. Replaying a message will have the same effect as replaying the original file

Comment: I agree. But If I want to transform a 1GB size file when an exception occurs it may redirect to the error handler-reference which configured DLQ Queue such as SEDA or any JMS Queue(Personally I am using AMQ). AMQ cant store 1GB file or messsage in Queue. At this point time if I used SEDA: or Direct: In the worst case if the Camel application got down or crashed that temporary SEDA or Direct holding message got vanished.